# How to gracefully shut down a Kafka channel adapter?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I'm using a `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` to consume messages from a Kafka topic. These messages are placed on a channel, and processed synchronously by a single thread.

I'd like to be able to gracefully shut down the system, meaning that no more messages are consumed from the topic, and messages that are being processed should be finished before shutting down.

I can call the `stop()` method on the channel `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`, but I'm not sure what happens with the thread that might currently be processing a message. To investigate this behaviour, I've been using a dummy component that simply sleeps for a while, to test what happens if I shut it down. It turns out that an `InterruptedException` is thrown, which could mean that downstream processing might not finish normally.

What is a correct way to gracefully shut down a Kafka channel adapter, which guarantees that messages in process will be able to finish?

Comment: This kind of questions assumes some test-case or Spring Boot application to play from our side. OTOH, share, please share the StackTrace as well. Looking into the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` code I don't see what interrupts the Thread. It just exists normally from the `while (this.active) {`

Comment: But can you confirm that calling `stop()` is intended to gracefully shut down the adapter, with the characteristics I described?

Comment: That is its intention. Everything works ok until you confirm opposite.

Comment: I think @ArtemBilan assumes you are using 2.x; the older 1.x version with the 0.8.x.x kafka client might work differently.